Fama&French models for asset returns applied to European Market
I am trying to use the F&F 3-factor and 5-factor models for the European Market (monthly data frequency). I downloaded the dataset provided by Fama&French and tried to apply the regressions for the 300 biggest EU companies. However, my questions are:

they use the yield on US T-bill. Wouldn't it be more appropriate to use the yield of German bund if considering the European Market?
I don't manage to find which market portfolio they're using to estimate the factor "excess market returns". When using their dataset, the betas I get for most of the factors are statistically not significant at 5% significance level. I tried to make the same exercise with CAPM against the excess market return factor from FF dataset (vs. the excess market return factor considering the market portfolio as being the MSCI Europe index). The result was that the betas in the first case were not statistically significant (5% level), while with the market portfolio being the MSCI Europe index, all the betas were statically significant. Could someone tell me which market portfolio did they consider in computing the factor?
Since I am using the log-returns for the stocks under analysis, would it be correct just to ignore (for simplicity) the currency in which the different stocks are quoted?

